# Meta inforation for RealmObject's entities?

Tags: android, realm

I'm working on a project with lots of seperate data.
I'm not even half done and right now I have 18 different Entities.
The data from these entities comes from our Internal Api.

I Was trying to convert to Realm since I've implemented this with extreme ease in our swift Project.

However I can't seem to find a solution to what I'm encountering now after rewriting nearly the entire app core (api/databasewise). I need to know which path the Entity should look to fetch more information or post/patch changes. In the previous version using SQLLite I had an abstract class which would require the Entities to have a method returning a string as path.

Now I cannot have an abstract class between RealmObject and the Entity, ok so I changed this to an Interface requiring these methods.

As I'm finally ready to compile I found out that I cannot have anything but properties & Getters & Setters in my entities.

What would be a proper solution to provide this data? I'm afraid of the idea of having a big if/else/switch Helper class to give me back the path based on the class.

In Swift I've added class functions just because there is no abstraction, but since I'm using abstract classes to update/fetch/load data from the API calling a static variable would probably require me to know exactly which class Instance I'm handling, that would seem impossible right now.

**TL;DR**
So, how do I provide some meta info on my RealmObject classes which don't belong in the database such as Api Paths.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. At what level do you want to save the data? Is it for every class of for every class instance? You could use static fields or the @Ignore annotation.

Comment: I don't want to save any data, I want to add some configuration.
So I want to add a path to our API in the entity itsel (so in the RealmObject Class).

I didn't think of the Ignore, maybe I could add a property with the path and annotate it with ignore? I'll try this.

Comment: So I implemented @Ignore path var, this works just fine.

If you want to put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use static fields or the @Ignore annotation.

Adding the @Ignore prevents realm from saving them into the DataBase, and you can still use getters and setters and add these with an interface.